# how to cast a varchar column using propel and symfony 1.4

Tags: casting, symfony1, propel, varchar

I got a table with a varchar(255) column named "value" where i can store numbers and text, in some point of my web application i need to do some comparissions, and when i try to compare an integer value not always got the right result, my code looks:

$c->getNewCriterion(MyTablePeer::VALUE, $filter, Criteria::GREATER_THAN);

Example:

MyTable.value = 6

$filter = 5

works great, fil, but if $filter = 10 or greater dont work properly,

think need to cast column value to integer so i could make a right comparision, it's my question, how can i cast using propel ?

$c->getNewCriterion(MyTablePeer::VALUE, $filter, Criteria::GREATER_THAN);

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

$c->getNewCriterion(MyTablePeer::VALUE, 'CAST('. MyTablePeer::VALUE .' AS SIGNED) > '. $filter, Criteria::CUSTOM);